# Setting a background image for ion-tabs

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set a background image for my tab-bar or nav-bar. I'm able to set it for a single tab icon but not for the bar itself.

index.html (the only tag inside body):

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

tabs.html:

```
<div>
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-top tabs-back" ng-class="{'tabs-item-hide': hideTabs}" ng-controller="TabsController as Tabs">
    <ion-tab title="Back" class="tabs-color" icon="ion-arrow-left-a"  on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('back')" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('back')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-back"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Play" class="tabs-color tabs-back" icon="ion-ios-game-controller-b" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('play')" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('play')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-play"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Game"  href="#/tabs/game" hidden='true'>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-game"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Share" class="tabs-color"  icon="ion-ios-camera" href="#/tabs/share" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('share')" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('share')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-share"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Achievements" class="tabs-color"  icon="ion-trophy"  on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('achievements')" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('achievements')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-achievements"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Settings" class="tabs-color"  icon="ion-ios-settings-strong" href="#/tabs/settings" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('settings')" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('settings')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-settings"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Login" icon="ion-log-in" href="#/tabs/login" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('login')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-login"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Score" class="tabs-color"  href="#/tabs/score" icon="ion-ribbon-a" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('score')" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('score')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-score"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Time" class="tabs-color" href="#/tabs/achievements-time" icon="ion-ios-timer" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('achievements-time')" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('achievements-time')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-achievements-time"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Moves" class="tabs-color" href="#/tabs/achievements-moves" icon="ion-ios-speedometer" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('achievements-moves')" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('achievements-moves')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-achievements-moves"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Likes" class="tabs-color" href="#/tabs/achievements-likes" icon="ion-thumbsup" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('achievements-likes')" hidden={{!Tabs.tabShow('achievements-likes')}}>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-achievements-likes"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Tutorial"  href="#/tabs/tutorial" hidden='true' hide-tabs>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-tutorial"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Message"  href="#/tabs/message" hidden='true' hide-tabs>
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-message"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
</div>
```

css:

> .tabs-back {
>         background-image: url("../img/background4.jpg") !important;
>           background-size: cover;
>       }

Now tabs-back css works for ion-tab (play) but not for ion-tabs. I was thinking I should probably set this class to the nav-bar but I don't think I have one...
I believe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but I'm a beginner so no idea what to do.

Please help, Thanks

after further manually changing classes under 'inspect element' I have found out that removing 'tabs' from the fist 'div' class and adding 'tabs-back' the background image appears. So I guess I need to override ionic's 'tabs' css declaration. If you think I'm correct where could I edit that?

```
<div class="tab-nav tabs">
    <ion-tab class="tabs-color" icon="ion-arrow-left-a" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('back')" hidden="true"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab class="tabs-color tabs-back" icon="ion-ios-game-controller-b" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('play')" hidden="false"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab href="#/tabs/game" hidden="true"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab class="tabs-color" icon="ion-ios-camera" href="#/tabs/share" on-select="Tabs.tabSelect('share')" hidden="false"></ion-tab>
```

Comment: when you run your code open your inspect element to see what target class you need to edit/where it is being set

Comment: I have tried to set it manually to figure it out using inspect element but with no success. That's why I thought I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I will add the 'inspect' to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ion-tabs directive then the class name is not the class name for the tab bar. Instead you will have to use that class name to refer to the tab bar

```
.tabs-back  .tab-nav{

    background-color: transparent  !important;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    background-image: url("../img/background4.jpg") !important; background-size: cover; 
 }
```